# Using multiple RecyclerView with one Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 `RecyclerView` to display most visited market, close by markets and favorite markets.

I have created 3 difference instance of `MarketAdapter` class for the three `RecyclerView`

Everything works fine, but my `Activity` implements one `OnClickListener` and I cant figure out which adapter was clicked. Is it possible to programmatically determine the `Adapter` that was clicked from the `OnClickListener`?

Here is my `MarketAdapter Class`

```
public class MarketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketAdapter.ViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Markets> mMarket = new ArrayList<>();
Context mContext;
private final MarketsItemsClickListener mItemsClickListener;
private final MarketLongClickListener mLongClickListener;
private final MarketClickListener mClickListener;

public MarketAdapter(Context context, MarketsItemsClickListener itemsClickListener, MarketClickListener clickListener, MarketLongClickListener longClickListener){
    mContext = context;
    mItemsClickListener = itemsClickListener;
    mLongClickListener = longClickListener;
    mClickListener = clickListener;
}

public interface MarketLongClickListener{
    void onLongClick(int position);
}

public interface MarketClickListener{
    void onClick(int position);
}

public interface MarketsItemsClickListener{
    void imageViewOnClickListener(View view, int position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutForListItem = R.layout.list_market;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.bindView(i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(mMarket != null) return mMarket.size();
    return 0;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<Markets> markets){
    mMarket = markets;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addData(Markets market, int position){
    mMarket.add(0, market);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Markets getItem(int position){return mMarket.get(position);}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener{

    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mNameTextView, mCityTextView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        mCityTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_text_view);

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bindView(int position){
        Markets market = getItem(position);

        mCityTextView.setText(market.getCity());
        mNameTextView.setText(market.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get position of Adapter
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        //Handle the click
        mClickListener.onClick(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

and `OnClickListener` from `Activity`

```
@Override
public void onClick(int position) {}
```

Comment: does your most visited, close by and fav. market views has same UI structure. or little 
bit different.

Comment: You don't need 3 adapters you need 3 different `view-holders`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass a tag in the constructor and get that tag back via a click listener to identify the click as

```
private final MarketsItemsClickListener mItemsClickListener;
private final MarketLongClickListener mLongClickListener;
private final MarketClickListener mClickListener;
private final String mTag;

public MarketAdapter(Context context, MarketsItemsClickListener itemsClickListener, MarketClickListener clickListener, MarketLongClickListener longClickListener, String tag){
    mTag = tag
    mContext = context;
    mItemsClickListener = itemsClickListener;
    mLongClickListener = longClickListener;
    mClickListener = clickListener;
}
```

Modify the listener as

```
public interface MarketClickListener{
    void onClick(int position, String tag);
}
```

and the listener code in activity as

```
@Override
public void onClick(int position, String tag) {
    switch(tag){
        case "adapter1":
        break;
        case "adapter2":
        break;
        case "adapter3":
        break;
    }
}
```

and create adapter object as

```
 MarketAdapter adapter = new MarketAdapter("adapter1"....); 
 MarketAdapter adapter1 = new MarketAdapter("adapter2"....); 
 MarketAdapter adapter2 = new MarketAdapter("adapter3"....);
```

and use

```
mClickListener.onClick(position, mTag);
```

Note: You can use enums as well

Answer (score 2):

You can add an attribute inside `MarketAdapter` so that you can tell what instance is that.

Change your custom click listener to receive the adapter type:

```
public interface MarketClickListener {
    //You can change this to receive any data you want from the adapter
    void onClick(int position, int adapterType);
}
```

Add the constants, the identifier attribute and change the listener in your adatper:

```
public class MarketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MarketAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    //The constants types
    public static int MOST_VISITED_MARKETS = 1;
    public static int CLOSE_BY_MARKETS = 2;
    public static int FAVORITE_MARKETS = 3;
    //New attribute
    private int adapterType;

    ...
    //Keep the listener
    private final MarketClickListener mClickListener;

        public MarketAdapter(Context context, MarketsItemsClickListener itemsClickListener, MarketClickListener clickListener, MarketLongClickListener longClickListener, int adapterType){
            ...
            //Set the type
            adapterType = adapterType;
        }

        ...

}
```

In your activity:

```
mostVisitedRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MarketAdapter(this,itemsClickListener,clickListener,longClickListener,MarketAdapter.MOST_VISITED_MARKETS ));
closeByRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MarketAdapter(this,itemsClickListener,clickListener,longClickListener,MarketAdapter.CLOSE_BY_MARKETS));
favoritesRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MarketAdapter(this,itemsClickListener,clickListener,longClickListener,MarketAdapter.FAVORITE_MARKETS));
```

In your view holder, change the `onClick`:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Get position of Adapter
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        //Handle the click
        mClickListener.onClick(position,adapterType);
    }
```

I didn't test this but I think it will do the trick. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it this way, I would add a new variable to the adapters constructor, and then use a case/if statement to determine what you want to do in your onbindviewholder.